# Dynamic Partition on tabular model 1200 using visual basic 2015 in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, tabular-model

I am using visual studio 2015, sql server 2016 and tabular model 1200. I am trying to create a dynamic partitions on the existing cube by creating SSIS package using script task and visual basic coding. So can any one specify the approach to create a dynamic partition every month and process the created partition every night. I searched through online and I didn't find any example with this environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would study this [white paper](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-as-automated-partition-management/) and the [AsPartitionProcessing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Analysis-Services/tree/master/AsPartitionProcessing) sample for ideas. Ignore that it targets Azure Analysis Services as it should work against your SSAS instance if you use that servername instead of asazure:// as the servername. It uses the Tabular Object Model (TOM).